# iphone programming ?. Change UITableViewCellEditingStyle image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I just need to know is it possible to change UITableViewCellEditingStyle image ?. If possible please tell me How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any delegate methods for changing the editing-style view.

You could change the editing button title with the delegate method [`-tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW26), however.

You could also override `UITableViewCell` and create a custom cell with [`UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellEditingStyle) and a custom editing style behavior and appearance.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're still interested you can actually get this to work by intercepting `willTransitionToState` and `didTransitionToState` in a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. The solution does involve "hacking" around in the cell view hierarchy. Look for the description of `recursiveDescription` on `UIView` on how to "dump" a hierarchy, but you will find a `UIImageView` of which you can change the `.image` property...

Fairly ugly hack, but does not actually use any private api.